# How to define a trigger ON COMMIT in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

Is there any way in oracle database to define trigger which will be fired synchronously before COMMIT (and ROLLBACK if it throws exception) in case when specified table is changed?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

There is no ON COMMIT trigger mechanism in Oracle. There are workarounds however:

1. You could use a materialized view with ON COMMIT REFRESH and add triggers to this MV. This would allow you to trigger the logic when a base table has been modified *at the time of commit*. If the trigger raises an error, the transaction will be rolled back (you will lose all uncommited changes).
2. You can use DBMS_JOB to defer an action to after the commit. This would be an asynchronous action and may be desirable in some cases (for example when you want to send an email after the transaction has been successful). If you roll back the primary transaction, the job will be cancelled. The job and the primary session are independent: if the job fails the main transaction will not be rolled back.

In your case, you could probably use option (1). I personnaly don't like to code business logic in triggers since it adds a lot of complexity but technically I think it would be doable.

Comment: Thank you. Option #1 is convenient for my case.

Comment: Of course a good solution. Just consider, that ON COMMIT REFRESH is part of the current transaction and delays the commit until the refresh has finished as well.
In case, the FAST REFRESH is complex and not fast enough, it might slow down the whole application and lead to more blockings and locks.
If FAST REFRESH is not possible, then maybe think about asynchronous refresh by a regular job.

Comment: "You can use DBMS_JOB to defer an action to after the commit.". I have not understood how the job will be executed as a result of the commit. Can you please provide some more information?

Comment: @MarinosAn: From the [DBMS_JOB documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/arpls/DBMS_JOB.html): *Your job will not be available for processing by the job queue in the background until it is committed*. Of note, as of 2023: DBMS_JOB has been superceded by DBMS_SCHEDULER.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similiar problem, but option 1 was unfortunately not convenient for my case.

Another possible solution, which is also suggested by "Ask Tom", is to specify a stored procedure and simply call that procedure before executing the COMMIT.
This solution is only convenient if you have access to the code which executes the COMMIT, but for my case this was the easiest solution.