# How to catch the event where in PL/SQL code the first commit occurs in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, events, plsql, commit

Is the way in Oracle automatically catch the event where in PL/SQL code the first commit occurs?

I have a big problem with PL/SQL procedure which should not do any commits but it does a commit somewhere.

This procedure runs a huge amount of pl/sql code, a lot of dynamic pl/sql code, some packages are wrapped and some packages are not granted for debug.

Maybe someone had it a similar problem and can help me?

Comment: Is any of the dynamic code doing any DDL - including maybe a truncate - which would implicitly commit, something the original developer might not have been aware of?

Comment: do you know of any tables of which data is getting inserted & commited? If so you can add a before insert trigger and log the stack trace using `dbms_utility.format_call_stack`. Should give some idea at least

Comment: You could also use workarounds mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098771/how-to-define-a-trigger-on-commit-in-oracle) along with my above comment to get a stack trace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer:

```
ALTER SESSION DISABLE COMMIT IN PROCEDURE
```

This command disables the possibility of commit and, what is most
 important for me the oracle error message shows the exact place where
 in pl/sql code the commit is.

```
SQL> create or replace procedure tst_commit is
  2  begin
  3    dbms_output.put_line('before commit');
  4    COMMIT;
  5    dbms_output.put_line('after commit');
  6  end tst_commit;
  7  /
Procedure created

SQL> BEGIN
  2    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SESSION DISABLE COMMIT IN PROCEDURE';
  3    INSERT INTO viliusg.log VALUES(SYSDATE,'test commit');
  4    tst_commit;
  5     dbms_output.put_line('THE END');
  6  END;
  7  /
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SESSION DISABLE COMMIT IN PROCEDURE';
  INSERT INTO viliusg.log VALUES(SYSDATE,'test commit');
  tst_commit;
    dbms_output.put_line('THE END');
END;
ORA-00034: cannot COMMIT in current PL/SQL session
ORA-06512: at "FORPOST.TST_COMMIT", line 4
ORA-06512: at line 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Your PL/SQL block will never COMMIT the changes until and unless you have explicitly mentioned **COMMIT**.

However, you might have **DDL** statements executed as **dynamic SQL** which might be going for an implicit commit. Search for the commit in the code.

You could look into **USER_SOURCE**.

```
SELECT * 
   FROM USER_SOURCE
  WHERE NAME = '<PROCEDURE NAME IN UPPER CASE>'
  AND   TYPE = 'PROCEDURE'
  AND   UPPER(TEXT) LIKE '%COMMIT%'
```

**Update**

To find the DDL statements, you could look for keywords like **CREATE, DROP, ALTER**

```
SELECT * 
   FROM USER_SOURCE
  WHERE NAME = '<PROCEDURE NAME IN UPPER CASE>'
  AND   TYPE = 'PROCEDURE'
  AND   UPPER(TEXT) LIKE '%CREATE%'
  OR    UPPER(TEXT) LIKE '%DROP%'
  OR    UPPER(TEXT) LIKE '%ALTER%'
```

Comment: You missed some commands which causing a implicit `COMMIT`, e.g. `TRUNCATE`, `RENAME`, `FLASHBACK` .... Also consider other packages, esp. SYSTEM packages, e.g. `DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS` where I don't know if they commit or not.

Comment: @Wernfried, It is up to OP, he has got a direction now. And do you really mean `FLASHBACK` inside a procedure? Truncate and rename are fine, I could have added them, but, I would leave that to OP.