# Oracle: commit-level “trigger equivalent”?

Tags: oracle, triggers, commit, audit

Is there a way to catch a commit, and write some information such as the session id to a table?

I'm able to handle this easily enough in my code, but I'm interested in tracking information where someone is executing ad hoc DML.

Comment: Why won't your existing triggers catch ad hoc DML  - are you trying to catch changes to tables you don't have explicit triggers on? And have you looked at the built-in auditing technologies?

Comment: Is this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/4098771/409172 ?