# When using userenv('COMMITSCN'), got error ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Tags: sql, oracle

Recently when I use `userenv('COMMITSCN')` to capture the on-commit event. I met below error:

> ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

At first, I created a table with commit_id column:

```
create table test (COMMIT_ID NUMBER);
```

And below is my testing process:

```
SQL> INSERT INTO test(commit_id) VALUES(userenv('COMMITSCN'));

1 row inserted

SQL> INSERT INTO test(commit_id) VALUES(userenv('COMMITSCN'));

INSERT INTO test(commit_id) VALUES(userenv('COMMITSCN'))
ORA-01721: USERENV(COMMITSCN) invoked more than once in a transaction
SQL> commit;
commit

ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

The error ORA-01721 is correct, but ORA-00942 is not. I think the cause may be about privilege, but how can I know which table or view does not exist? Any tip is appreciated.

Oracle version:
Oracle Database 12c Standard Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: Thanks a_horse_with_no_name for editting my post.

Comment: Are you 100% sure this is related to your usage of userenv('COMMITSCN') and not related to something else, e.g. a materialized view that is configured as REFRESH ON COMMIT?

Comment: @FrankSchmitt Thanks. I am not 100% sure. I have rephrased my word. I will check the possible cause given by you. But when I commit other DML operations, no problem occurs.

Comment: It's a priviledge problem. For my user, it needs direct grants and prefix schema owner to the table or synonym if needed. I haven't found the solution so far. But I may not use userenv('COMMITSCN') and try check another workaround.

Comment: I used materialize view instead. For more detail, you can refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098771/how-to-define-a-trigger-on-commit-in-oracle